# Reinitializing rbac rights

Tags: database, authentication, yii2, roles, rbac

I'm implementing RBAC in project. rbac/init command has code

```
$auth = Yii::$app->getAuthManager();
$auth->removeAll();
```

This code removing all rights and assignments. I want to save pairs users and rights in auth_assignment table. I try to make solution to save auth_assignment table data when RBAC will reinitializing

```
$auth = Yii::$app->getAuthManager();
$data=Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select * from auth_assignment')->queryAll();
$auth->removeAll();
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('auth_assignment',['item_name','user_id','created_at'],$data);
```

What you think about that solution? Is it right? Thanks.

Comment: This won't work. `DbManager::removeAll` removes also all roles, permissions and rules not just assignments. You won't be able to insert anything into auth_assigment table because item_name wouldn't exist in auth_item table. After removeAll you need to create everything again not just assignments.

Comment: why are you removing all `auth_assignment` data? Are you setting up the project for the first time ? if **yes** you dont need to do it and if **No** , then **you should not** be doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I have went through this situation and found two ways to deal with assign permissions:

1. First way is to work with console:

   `yii rbac/init`

   This way you have to have controller in console/command:

   ```
   use Yii;
   use yii\console\Controller;

   class RbacController extends Controller
   {
       public function actionInit()
       {
           $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
           $auth->removeAll();
           //...
       }
   }
   ```

   2. Install extension `yii2mod/yii2-rbac` and assign roles dynamically. Here is the [link](https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-rbac)  .

I found the second option more productive and safe, since you keep already assigned roles saved.Hope it will helps.